# Text is next to each other instead of in two lines CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create my CV as a web page and I'm having troubles with aligning my H1 with the menu (the table). They are in one line next to each other, but I want my table to be bellow the H1.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="uvod">
 <h1>Name of the page</h1>
 </div>
 <div>
  <ul class="uvod">
   <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="l">Introduction</a></li>
   <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Galery</a></li>
   <li><a href="">My work</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and here the CSS:

```
.uvod {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      position: fixed;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: justify;
      font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
      color: #F0F8FF;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
 }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: The code you provided appears to have them on two different lines. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/cshpkgno/

Comment: simply remove fixed

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to `display: flex` for a reason? If not, use the snippet below I think it is what you were asking for? Let me know.

```css
.uvod {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  color: #F0F8FF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.uvod h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.uvod ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="uvod">
  <h1>Name of the page</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="l">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Galery</a></li>
    <li><a href="">My work</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it did what I wanted to, but it also made the whole text appear on the top left corner instead of in the middle of the page as it was before 
(and the li items were ok, I wanted to have the li items in one line that will be bellow H1)

Comment: Center of the page width or of height and width?

Comment: Everything is centered now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I did it with margin and it works as well (I don't need any other items on the page, so this should do I think)

Answer (score 0):

I will first of all suggest you use `position:relative` and `display:block`

```
.uvod {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: justify;
   font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
   color: #F0F8FF;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

See sample here -> https://jsfiddle.net/85em2hm0/

Comment: why ? you may notice that we deal with `div` which by default it's a block element and no need width:100% ... also removing the flex makes some property irrelevant, and why position:relative?

Comment: Thanks, it did what I wanted to, but it also made the whole text appear on the top left corner instead of in the middle of the page as it was before

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you expected to be the resulting layout.
Anyways, i have tried to come up with something better suited for you case.

Actually you don't need to use flex in this case at all (not yet at least).
What you needed to fix you code is that when using flex, most of the times you have a container representing each section and add items into this container, and since you've used the same class `.uvod` twice and it was marked as fixed, both occupied the same spot, overlapping. One way to fix it was to use a single wrapping flex `.uvod` around the `h1` and `ul` tags. And adding `flex-flow:column` to the container.

A simpler way is to not use flex at all.. if you don't need any fancy alignment and positioning, just keep with simple `display: block`.

Have a look at this fiddle with the fixes i have talked. (The commented code is a fix for your version, and the other is an alternative using flex only to correctly align the summary).

```css
 /*     .uvod {
       flex-flow: column;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       display: flex;
       position: fixed;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: justify;
       font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
       color: #F0F8FF;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       letter-spacing: 3px;
     }
      */
     body {
       font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
     }
     
     .title {
       text-transform: uppercase;
       letter-spacing: 3px;
       text-align: center;
       /* color: #F0F8FF; */
     }
     
     .section {
       width: 100%:
       margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
     
     .summary-wrapper {
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
     }
     
     .summary {
       list-style: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       letter-spacing: 3px;
     }
```

```html
<!-- <div class="uvod">
  <h1>Name of the page</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="l">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Galery</a></li>
    <li><a href="">My work</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> -->

<!-- Alternative -->
<h1 class="title">Name of the page</h1>
<div class="section summary-wrapper">
  <ul class="summary">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Galery</a></li>
    <li><a href="">My work</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `new class` for the `<ul>`. This example doesn't use `flex`. The `.uvod div` has a `fixed position` and `top:50%;`. All that is needed now is to set a `negative top margin to center it`.

To center the `.uvod div` perfectly in the middle vertically you would need to know the height of the div, then give it a negative top margin of `half its height in px`.

For example, if the `.uvod div` had `height:400px`, then you would write `margin-top:-200px;`.

Here is the code, run the snippet at the bottom and check [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cahxxe0L/) with the same code so you can test on a bigger background:

```css
.uvod
{
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-50.5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  color: #F0F8FF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

h1
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}

.uvodUL
{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.uvodUL li
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="uvod">
 <h1>Name of the page</h1>
 <ul class="uvodUL">
   <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="l">Introduction</a></li>
   <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Galery</a></li>
   <li><a href="">My work</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** If you don't know the height beforehand then you can use `percentages %` (percentage of parent height - in this case the height of the document body).
If you need to adjust the value you can use `media queries` to change for `different resolutions`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use flex-direction: 'column' in css

and apply class="uvod" to both the divs instead of ul:

Something like this:

```
<div class="uvod">
 <h1>Name of the page</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="uvod">
  <ul >
   <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="l">Introduction</a></li>
   <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Galery</a></li>
   <li><a href="">My work</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked too, but I have the same problem as with the other answears - my text is now in the top left corner instead of the middle of the page. 
(and thank for pointing out that I had one class in div and other in ul, I tried to put it all in one div and it works too)

Comment: Use this link http://flexboxfroggy.com/ to lean CSS flex box , it will make learning fun and easy